# trying to apply desktop css and mobile css on html.but css not working.pls advise

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply desktop css and mobile css on my html page.
But css is not working.
HTML validator is showing me following errors:

> Error: Bad value screen and (minwidth:768px) for attribute media on element link:
>   Expected a CSS media feature but saw minwidth instead.
>   From line 9, column 2; to line 9, column 97

```html
</title>
<link href="desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (minwidth:768px)" />
<link  Error: Bad value screen and (maxwidth:480px) for attribute media on element link: Expected a CSS media feature but saw maxwidth instead.  From line 10, column 2; to line 10, column 80  8px)" />
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (maxwidth:480px)" /></head>
```

pls advise.Thanks

Comment: You forgot the hyphen: `min-width`, not `minwidth`

Answer (score 0):

You’re close, it should be

```
@media screen only and (min-width: 786px)
```

Note the hyphen after min.

Comment: Should be colon instead of equality sign -> `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)`

Comment: Oh ya sorry not am equal sign. My bad

Comment: glad if I could help!